# How to set up Virtual Hosting on a Mac (local)

Tags: macos, apache, vhosts

How can I setup a virtual hosting on my Mac. It should be easy by adding a `127.0.0.1` line to the hosts file and editing the apache configuration. But for some reason, it doesn't work with me...

And no, MAMP is not an option since you can't setup vhosts in MAMP (except if you buy the MAMP Pro...)
Any advice?

Comment: It works just fine, i have several vhosts set up on my OS X box under apache.  Make sure that you are using name-based virtual hosting AND that if you are using apache that is distributed with OS X and the vhosts config is in a separate file (e.g. in /etc/apache2/other/httpd-vhosts.conf) that it is actually getting included. Include /private/etc/apache2/other/*.conf

Answer (score 3):

It works just fine, i have several vhosts set up on my OS X box under apache.  Make sure that you are using name-based virtual hosting AND that if you are using apache that is distributed with OS X and the vhosts config is in a separate file (e.g. in /etc/apache2/other/httpd-vhosts.conf) that it is actually getting included. Also you can always test `apachectl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS` to see if the virtual hosts are actually getting defined.

Comment: Allright, great to hear it possible :) The only httpd-vhosts.conf file I've got, is in `/etc/apache2/extra`. Do I need to duplicate this and place it in another folder?

Comment: thats the right place... make sure that your /etc/apache2/httpd.conf has a line that Includes this file into it uncommented.  And once you add an entry to /etc/hosts file you should make sure to run `dscacheutil -flushcache` command to flush the directory service  cache (which controls the name lookups).

Comment: I did everything you asked for, but Safari isn't able to make a connection to my local hosted website...

Comment: are you able to ping your hostname in the terminal? Also make sure that apache is bound to localhost ... try telnet localhost 80 in terminal to make sure that it's binding to localhost ...

Comment: If not, how can I bind apache to my localhost?

Comment: What does the `Listen` line say in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf ?

Comment: I'll answer your questions and try your suggestions later this day. Cause right now, I'm at work and I don't have my Mac with me. Thanks a lot!